# get twitter favourites with registered user

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, sttwitterapi

I want to get user's favorites using following API [favorites/list](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-favorites-list)

Twitter has to types of rate limits: 
- per app 
- per user

My goal is to authorize user and make this request signing it with user token. to have rate limits for user, not for the whole application. 
But I can't understand from [authentication docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request), how I should pass user token in get favourites request

Answer (score 0):

#### TwitterOAuth

There's a handy PHP library called [TwitterOAuth](https://twitteroauth.com/) ([code](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)) that does most of the heavy lifting for you. There's a lists of other libraries in different languages too ([Twitter Libraries](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries.html)).

#### Usage

---

To instantiate the class `TwitterOAuth` and set your keys, simply do this:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
```

To grab your 10 most recent [favorites/likes](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-favorites-list):

```
$statuses = $connection->get("favorites/list", ["count" => 10]);
```

This will return an object. You can print out the object as JSON:

```
foreach ($statuses as $tweet) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($tweet);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

[php](/questions/tagged/php) [twitter](/questions/tagged/twitter)